# Talend BigData Error on Run

Tags: talend

I created my 1st BigData project.  My connection works properly and I configured a  tMongoDbInput with a simple query and I connect it to a TLogRow to dump the output.

Talend BigData Version 7.0.1
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

Why does Talend throw this error on run.

```
org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorException: Job compile errors
```

At least job "GetNewClaims" has a compile errors, please fix and export again.
Error Line: 1
Detail Message: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
There may be some other errors caused by JVM compatibility. Make sure your JVM setup is similar to the studio.

```
at org.talend.designer.runprocess.JobErrorsChecker.checkLastGenerationHasCompilationError(JobErrorsChecker.java:338)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.DefaultRunProcessService.checkLastGenerationHasCompilationError(DefaultRunProcessService.java:464)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessService.checkLastGenerationHasCompilationError(RunProcessService.java:316)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateBuildInfo(ProcessorUtilities.java:812)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateCode(ProcessorUtilities.java:586)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateCode(ProcessorUtilities.java:1736)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessContext$1.run(RunProcessContext.java:582)

at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)

at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)

at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:527)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:284)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:1190)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessContext.exec(RunProcessContext.java:534)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ui.ProcessComposite.exec(ProcessComposite.java:1401)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ui.views.ProcessView$RunAction.run(ProcessView.java:701)

at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ui.actions.RunProcessAction.run(RunProcessAction.java:58)

at org.talend.designer.core.debug.JobLaunchConfigurationDelegate$1.run(JobLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:84)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)

at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)

at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)

at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)

at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:265)

at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't fully configured with env't variables.

redid my JAVA_HOME to the JRE and got my path set properly and Talend started working.